# An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, badimageformatexception

For whatever reason when we started getting this exception message on one of our servers, all are Window server 2008 R2. The website site was fine a few weeks ago and we can't tell what has changed. The application pool has enable 32 bit apps set to true. We can deploy the same source code to another server and it works but not vice versa.

Anyone have any ideas?

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +0
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +645
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +140

```
[UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +303
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction, Boolean throwOnClosedConnection) +124
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(Boolean throwOnClosedConnection) +89
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__b() +18
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +314
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy) +161
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass9.<SaveChanges>b__6() +21
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +153
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) +226
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +141

[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +209
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +27
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +20
   SecureEDI.PMS.DataAccess.CrudEFRepository`1.Save() +35
   SecureEDI.PMS.DataAccess.CrudEFRepository`1.Create(T entity) +183
   SecureEDI.PMS.BusinessLogic.CrudEFManager`1.Create(T entity) +61
   SecureEDI.PMS.Core.Exceptions.ExceptionHandler.LogException(Exception e) +1724
   SecureEDI.PMS.Core.Exceptions.ExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception exception) +1434
   SecureEDI.PMS.Core.Exceptions.ExceptionHandler..ctor(Exception exception) +24
   SecureEDI.PMS.Web.Controllers.BaseController.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) +582
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +18
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +46
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +820
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +148
```

Comment: Does this happen if you re-deploy the code to the server causing the trouble ?

Comment: We can copy/re-deploy the site to another server and have it work fine.

Comment: Do you happen to have HP Mercury installed on the server to monitor performance?